# Install ruby 2.6.5 in windows 10

Tags: ruby

I want to install ruby on windows 10 using rvm. I read the documentation but I am not able to install ruby on my computer.
Please help me to install ruby in windows 10.
Thank You

Comment: You need to put what you already did. what is your error. in what step you are stuck in order to help you

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) with Ubuntu, then install [rvm & ruby](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm).

So You would have the best from the linux in your Windows platform.